# Exporting from react to rtf

Tags: reactjs, export, rtf

I'm building a meeting management app using react.
I want to add an end meeting button that exports a summary of the meeting that was stored in a state.
Can I export the content of the state to an RTF file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an RTF using the `Blob` object.

**See the example below.**

```
import React from "react";

class MyApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      summary: "Hello this is summary"
    };
  }

  onEndMeeting = () => {
    const element = document.createElement("a");
    const file = new Blob([this.state.summary], { type: "text/plain" });
    element.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    element.download = "myFile.txt";
    document.body.appendChild(element);
    element.click();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.onEndMeeting}>End Meeting</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MyApp;
```

Stackblitz Demo: [Click here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nyuuow?file=src%2FApp.js)